# Radio buttons & Next JS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

In order to expose one issue I am facing in a Next JS app, I created the following test app that I called *radio-flash-test*.

Here are the commands I used to create the app:

```
 % npx create-next-app@latest
 .....
 % cd radio-flash-test
 % heroku create radio-flash-test
```

These are the file contents for the source code:

File **app/page.tsx** :

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import RadioDisplayMng from './components/RadioDisplayMng'

export default function Home() {
  return (
<main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
      <div className="z-10 w-full max-w-5xl items-center    justify-between font-mono text-sm lg:flex">
      <RadioDisplayMng />
      </div>
    </main>
  )
}
```

File **app/components/RadioDisplayMng.tsx** :

```
'use client'

import React, {useEffect,useState} from "react";
import RadioChoice from "./RadioChoice";
import "./RadioDisplayMng.css";
import Flash from "./Flash";


export default function SentenceDisplayMng() {
    const [choiceType, setChoiceType] = useState(1)
    const [typeChecks, setTypeChecks] = useState([true,false,   false])

    useEffect(() => {
        switch (choiceType) {
            case 1:
                setTypeChecks([true,false,false])
                break;
            case 2:
                setTypeChecks([false,true,false])
                break;
            case 3:
                setTypeChecks([false,false,true])
                break;
            default:
                console.log('Unexpected case in useEffect=' +choiceType)
                break;
        }
    }, [choiceType])

    return <div>
        <FlashBox checks={typeChecks} />
    <RadioChoice
            actionFunc={(v) => setChoiceType(v)} 
            radChecks={typeChecks} />
    </div>
} /* End of SentenceDisplayMng */


function FlashBox({checks}:{checks: boolean[]}) {
    return <div className="flasBx">
        <Flash color={checks[0]?"red":"grey"} />
        <Flash color={checks[1]?"green":"grey"} />
        <Flash color={checks[2]?"blue":"grey"} />
    </div>
} /* End of FlashBox */
```

File **app/components/RadioChoice.tsx** :

```
import React, {useState,ChangeEvent} from "react";
import "./RadioChoice.css";

export default function RadioChoice(
    {radChecks,actionFunc=()=>{}}:
    {
        radChecks: boolean[]
        actionFunc?: (v:number) => void
    }) {


    function radioSelect(evt:ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
        console.log('radioSelect -> '+evt.target.value)
        if (typeof actionFunc===undefined) return
        actionFunc(parseInt(evt.target.value))
        console.log('actionFunc called!')
    } /* End of radioSelect */


    return (
        <div className='xrcTpSlctBlk'>
            <label className='xrcTpLbl'>
                Choose among the following
            </label>
            <div className='xrcTpRdbnBlk'>
                <div className='rdbBlk'>
                    <div className='rdbtn'>
                        <input type='radio' name='exoTp' value= {1}
                            checked={radChecks[0]}
                            onChange={e=>radioSelect(e)} />
                    </div>
                    <div className='trsTpLbl'>Choice One</div>
                </div>
                <div className='rdbBlk'>
                    <div className='rdbtn'>
                        <input type='radio' name='exoTp' value= {2}
                            checked={radChecks[1]}
                            onChange={e=>radioSelect(e)} />
                    </div>
                    <div className='trsTpLbl'>Choice Two</div>
                </div>
                <div className='rdbBlk'>
                    <div className='rdbtn'>
                        <input type='radio' name='exoTp' value= {3}
                            checked={radChecks[2]}
                            onChange={e=>radioSelect(e)} />
                    </div>
                    <div className='trsTpLbl'>Choice Three</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

File **app/components/Flash.tsx** :

import "./Flash.css";

```
export default function Flash({color}:{color: string}) {
    let colrDsk = 'grey'
    if (color=='red') colrDsk = 'red'
    else if (color=='green') colrDsk = 'green'
    else if (color=='blue') colrDsk = 'blue'
    const dskCls = "flasDisc "+colrDsk
    return (<div className={dskCls}></div>)
} /* End of Flash */
```

The app displays three lights at the top; red, green and blue, which can be switched on and off using three radio buttons. Clicking on the first one should set light on the red, the second on the green and the third on the blue.

Finaly the app can be seen and tried out here:
https://radio-flash-test-6a054408fa42.herokuapp.com/

When one tries it, one will notice that it sometimes stops working as expected.
I would like to have a second pair of eyes take a look and see if a mistake can be spotted out inside the code. Many thanks for any relevant tip.

[image]

In case this could be useful, here is the contents of the **package.json** file :

```
{
    "name": "radio-flash-test",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
      "dev": "next dev",
      "build": "next build",
      "start": "next start",
      "lint": "next lint"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "@types/node": "20.4.4",
      "@types/react": "18.2.15",
      "@types/react-dom": "18.2.7",
      "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
      "eslint": "8.45.0",
      "eslint-config-next": "13.4.12",
      "next": "13.4.12",
      "postcss": "8.4.27",
      "react": "18.2.0",
      "react-dom": "18.2.0",
      "tailwindcss": "3.3.3",
      "typescript": "5.1.6"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if I remove name prop from radio input. Seems like onchange event doesn't fire but not sure why

Comment: Exactly, the onChange does not fire as you say. And "Why?" is my exact same question. Beside your suggestion of removing the name prop works. Do you have an explanation? I thought the name was needed to make a group of radio buttons.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).